# Text to wrap around informational box

Tags: formatting

I'd like to have an informational box placed to the edge of a page of text, and have the text wrap around it, like so:
[image]
How should I go about doing this?

Comment: `wrapfig` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short example using `wrapfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}%
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you put `0pt`? If the figures are wider than `0pt`?

Comment: @skpblack - From `wrapfig` manual: "...if you specify a width of zero (0pt), the actual width of the figure will determine the wrapping width."